# RSA Encryption C code

Tags: c, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I am having trouble doing my homework. 
I am doing an RSA application which can encrypt and decrypt.

The problem is that after I Input things to encrypt the results are weird and I can't decrypt anything. This is because when I copied the results of encryption which are symbols, I got more weird stuffs.

I'm guessing it has something to do with my formula getting negative ASCIIs as results.

Below is what I tried, and, in order to understand what I meant by weird, just compile and try it out(I have some unused stuffs which I haven't removed yet):

**Output**:

[image: Encrypting kevin]
[image: After Copying encrypted kevin to decrypt]

**Code**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#define boolean int
#define true 1
#define false 0
//===================================================//
int p = 0;
int q = 0;
int n = 0;
int m = 0;
int divider = 2;
int tempdivider = 2;
int initial = 0;
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
char msg[100];
char alphabet[27];
//===================================================//
void cls();
void menu();
void init();
void reinit();
void inputencrypt();
//int encrypt(int num);
void encrypt();
char decrypt(char text[]);
int fpb(int num);
int d(int num);
int primecheck(int a);
boolean checkdigit(char text[]);
//===================================================//

int main() {
    frontpage();
    init();
    menu();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
//===================================================//
void cls() {
    for (int i = 0;i < 25;i++) {
        printf("\n");
    }
}
//===================================================//
boolean checkdigit(char text[]) {
    int len = strlen(text);
    for (int i = 0;i < len;++i) {
        if (text[i]<'0' || text[i]>'9') {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
int primecheck(int a) {
    if (a == 1) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 2;i < a;i++) {
        if (a%i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
//===================================================//
void reinit() {
    for (int i = 1;i < 27;i++) {
        alphabet[i] = 'a' + i - 1;
    }
    p = 0;
    q = 0;
    n = 0;
    m = 0;
    divider = 2;
    tempdivider = 2;
    initial = 120;
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
}
void init() {
    reinit();
    do {
        printf("p = ");
        scanf("%d", &p);fflush(stdin);
        if (!primecheck(p)) {
            printf("must be prime number! \n");
        }
    } while (!primecheck(p));
    do {
        printf("q = ");
        scanf("%d", &q);fflush(stdin);
        if (!primecheck(q)) {
            printf("must be prime number! \n");
        }
    } while (!primecheck(q));
    n = p*q;
    m = (p - 1)*(q - 1);
    initial = m;
    x = fpb(m);
    y = d(m);
    printf("n = %d\n", n);
    printf("m = %d\n", m);
    printf("e = %d\n", x);
    printf("d = %d\n", y);
    system("pause");
}
//===================================================//
void menu() {
    char input[2];
    int input1 = 0;
    do {
        do {
            cls();
            printf("main menu\n");
            printf("================\n");
            printf("1. encrypt\n");
            printf("2. decrypt\n");
            printf("3. exit\n");
            printf(">> ");
            scanf("%s", input);fflush(stdin);
            if (checkdigit(input)) {
                input1 = atoi(input);
            }
        } while (!checkdigit(input));

        switch (input1) {
        case 1:
            int c;
            char encrypted[100];
            char word[100];
            printf("input word to encrypt : ");
            scanf(" %[^\n]", word);fflush(stdin);


            for (int i = 0;i < strlen(word);i++) {

                if (word[i] == ' ') {
                    encrypted[i] = ' ';
                    //i++;
                }
                else {
                    for (int j = 1;j < 27;j++) {
                        if (word[i] == alphabet[j]) {
                            c = 0;
                            c = pow(j, x);
                            c = c%n;
                            encrypted[i] = c;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            printf("\n\nWord ASCII      [   ");
            for (int i = 0;i < strlen(word);i++) {
                //printf("%d", c);
                printf("%d  ", word[i]);
            }
            printf("    ]\n");


            printf("\n\nEncrypted ASCII     [   ");
            for (int i = 0;i < strlen(word);i++) {
                //printf("%d", c);
                printf("%d  ", encrypted[i]);
            }
            printf("    ]\n");
            printf("\n\nEncrypted       [   ");
            for (int i = 0;i < strlen(word);i++) {
                //printf("%d", c);
                printf("%c", encrypted[i]);
            }
            printf("    ]");
            printf("\n\n\n");
            system("pause");
            break;
        case 2:
            int temp[100];
            char decrypted[100];
            char wordx[100];
            int h;
            printf("input word to decrypt : ");
            scanf(" %[^\n]", wordx);fflush(stdin);
            for (int i = 0;i < strlen(wordx);i++) {
                temp[i] = wordx[i];
                //temp[i] -= 97;
                //printf("%d ::: %c\n", temp[i], temp[i]);
            }
            for (int i = 0;i < strlen(wordx);i++) {
                if (wordx[i] == ' ') {
                    decrypted[i] = ' ';
                }
                else {
                    h = 0;
                    h = pow(temp[i], y);
                    h = h%n;
                    decrypted[i] = h;
                    for (int j = 1;j < 27;j++) {
                        if (decrypted[i] == j) {
                            decrypted[i] = alphabet[j];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            printf("\n\nWord ASCII      [   ");
            for (int i = 0;i < strlen(wordx);i++) {
                //printf("%d", c);
                printf("%d  ", wordx[i]);
            }
            printf("    ]\n");
            printf("\n\nDecrypted ASCII     [   ");
            for (int i = 0;i < strlen(wordx);i++) {
                //printf("%d", c);
                printf("%d  ", decrypted[i]);
            }
            printf("    ]\n");
            printf("\n\nDecrypted       [   ");
            for (int i = 0;i < strlen(wordx);i++) {
                //printf("%d", decrypted[i]);
                printf("%c", decrypted[i]);
            }
            printf("    ]");
            printf("\n\n\n");
            system("pause");
            break;
        }
    } while (input1 != 3);
}
//===================================================//
int fpb(int num) {
    if (!primecheck(num)) {
        if (num%divider == 0) {
            num = num / divider;
            divider = 2;
        }
        else {
            divider++;
        }
        fpb(num);
    }
    else if (primecheck(num)) {
        if (!primecheck(num + divider)) {
            tempdivider++;
            divider = tempdivider;
            num = initial;
            fpb(num);
        }
        else {
            return num + divider;
        }
    }
}
int d(int num) {
    for (int i = 1;i < num;i++) {
        if ((x*i) % num == 1) {
            return i;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a general comprehension problem. Your console is only able to represent 96 characters correctly (known as printable 7bit-ASCII characters, 0x20 to 0x7F), but a byte can hold 255 different values. Your encryption algorithm does not care about this limited range, it will encrypt any value in the range [0..255] into another value in the range [0..255]. So your ASCII input characters will most likely be encrypted into values that cannot be represented by your console correctly. Copy&Past will not work correctly for non-printable characters (like 0x0B, which is a tab).

But now you will wonder: Why does that work for e.g. E-Mails? Simply: Because those characters are converted into an ASCII representation. Please google a bit for Base64 encoding.

As an alternative, you can always stream your encrypted characters into a file and later read back from that. This way you will bypass the limitations of your console.

Btw: Please have a look at the documentation of `printf()` and you will know, why you get those negative values.

Answer (score 0):

The encrypt option has these three statements consecutively

```
c = 0;
c = pow(j, x);
c = c%n;
```

and the last of those will leave `c` in the range `0..(n-1)`.

Apart from that, there is no `else` clause and `int c;` can remain *uninitialised*.

So all in all it is inevitable that when you print `c` values as characters you will get "weird" results.

As for negative values, `char encrypted[100];` is probably `signed char` so any integer value in the range `128..255` assigned to that, although *undefined behaviour*, may possibly show up as a negative number because the `signed char` is promoted back to `int` when passed as format `%d` to `printf`.